# In ProcessPoolExecutor of concurrent.futures, BrokenProcessPool occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return x+1
        
def main():

    data = np.arange(100).reshape(10,-1)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for result in executor.map(func,data):
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected this code to result in the following:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
[21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]
[31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40]
[41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]
[51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60]
[61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70]
[71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]
[81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90]
[91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100]
```

the result was:

```
BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

But, the following code works

```
###
for result in executor.map(np.sum,data):
    print(result)
###
```

The result is

```
45
145
245
345
445
545
645
745
845
945
```

I thought because I created 'func' by myself.

Please tell me why the error is happening.

Comment: Code works as expected here (under Linux as well as Windows).

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook, is that related?

Comment: Most likely, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjupyter%5D+multiprocessing) the amount of problems with multiprocessing.